# grantRolesToUser fails with error "Could not find role: root"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongo-shell

Using mongosh in mongo compass, I've created a user for my database:

```
use test_db
db.createUser({user:'some_user', pwd: 'some_pass', roles:[]})
```

Now, when I try to assign root role to it, I get **could not find role: root@test_db**

```
db.grantRolesToUser(    "some_user",
    [
      { role: "root", db: "test_db" }
    ])
```

Isn't root role a built-in role? Why cannot I assign it? Currently, when I try to run an aggregate for instance, I get **MongoServerError: not authorized on test to execute command { aggregate: ...**.
That's why I want to assign the root role to get rid of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Role `root` is defined in `admin` database. In database `test_db` this role does not exist - unless you created it manually.

**Note:**

Except for roles created in the `admin` database, a role can only include privileges that apply to its database and can only inherit from other roles in its database.

A role created in the `admin` database can include privileges that apply to the `admin` database, other databases or to the cluster resource, and can inherit from roles in other databases as well as the `admin` database.

Actually, I don't know any reason to create user in other database than `admin`.

Comment: So, I tried removing the user from my test_db and keeping it in admin database with a root role. But the problem is I cannot connect to test_db with that user created in admin db. I use mongoose client with the following connection string: "mongodb://some_user:some_pass@localhost:27017/test_db" and authentication fails with test_db

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470